# Start application after installation

Tags: wix

I've googled around and found some topics like

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/run_program_after_install.htm

and

[Launch application after installation complete, with UAC turned on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282960/wix-launch-application-after-installation-complete-with-uac-turned-on)

but, i don't use any ui. Just simple installation!
So far

```
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApp" Directory="INSTALLDIR" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /C MyExe.exe" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
      <RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize" /> 
      <Custom Action="LaunchApp" After="InstallFinalize" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

but when i start the installer, a window pops up: "Please wait while Windows configures MyProgram". and on top of it comes cmd.exe just with a blinking cursor, when i close cmd i get message :"There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run." Though program remains opened.
How can i do that properly (without any UI)?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What happens if you use

```
ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /C start MyExe.exe"
```

Comment: Thank you Antony, that worked very well. I had no start keyword in ExeCommand!

Answer (score 7):

Set [Return](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_customaction.htm) to **asyncNoWait** for your custom action. This way the custom action runs and the installer doesn't wait for it or check its return code.

Comment: Thanks Cosmin, that almost worked. Command prompt didn't disappear. i had to close it manually! Got it now! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem that it also tried to run at uninstallation.. This way it runs only on installation, reparation and updating (changing)

```
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApp" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /C start MyFile.exe" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="LaunchApp" After="InstallFinalize">NOT REMOVE</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Information about `NOT REMOVE` could be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17608049/9758687