# What is wrong with this 'run executable' Wix xml code?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

I am trying to execute **my.exe** using **your.exe**. It's not working as expected.

Here is the code snippet:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="my_name" Language="1033" Version="1.11.5164" 
             Manufacturer="company" UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE">
       <Package Description="Test file in a Product" Comments="Simple test" 
                InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />
       <Media Id="1" Cabinet="simple.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
         <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles">
                <Directory Name="my_folder" Id="MY_FOLDER">
                  <Component Id="your.EXE" DiskId="1" Guid="*">
                    <File KeyPath="yes" Id="your.exe" Name="your.exe" 
                          Source="your.exe" />
                  </Component>  
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
        <Feature Id="MainFeature" Title="Main Feature" Level="1">
                   <ComponentRef Id="your.EXE" />
        </Feature>
        <CustomAction Id="StartAppOnExit" Property="StartAppOnExit" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /C your.exe my.exe " Execute="immediate" Return="asyncNoWait" /> 
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="StartAppOnExit" After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom> 

     </InstallExecuteSequence>
    </Product>
    </Wix>
```

Answer (score 0):

The custom action `StartAppOnExit` can't find **your.exe**.  Try using a `Directory` attribute instead of a `Property` attribute:

```
<CustomAction Id="StartAppOnExit" Directory="MY_FOLDER" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /C your.exe my.exe " Execute="immediate" Return="asyncNoWait" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="StartAppOnExit" After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>

</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

This should run **your.exe** passing the argument **my.exe**.

See also [Start application after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194936/start-application-after-installation).