# Wix - How to launch installed exe after installation?

Tags: wix

I use wix installer without UI and after installation I want to run "updater.exe"

I have already tried

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
     <Custom Action='LaunchInstalledExe' After='InstallFinalize'/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<CustomAction Id="LaunchInstalledExe"
     ExeCommand="updater.exe" 
     Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
     Execute="immediate" 
     Impersonate="yes" 
     Return="asyncWait" />
```

but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194936/start-application-after-installation and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271862/wix-how-to-run-exe-files-after-installation-from-installed-directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wix - How to run exe files after installation from installed directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271862/wix-how-to-run-exe-files-after-installation-from-installed-directory)

Comment: Are you sure you want to use "asyncWait"? Your installation will not finish until updater.exe completes and exits.